# WPF style triggered in ResourceDictionary applied to all instances?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, resourcedictionary

In my WPF project, I have defined a custom style for my `Button` with the key 'MainButton_1'.
The style includes a `MouseEnter` EventTrigger in the `ControlTemplate`, which gives the button a darker background when hovered over.

[image]
It worked well when the style is stored in `App.xaml` *(left portion of the image)*.
Recently I moved the style to a ResourceDictionary `AppUIResource.xaml` and here comes the funny part: **when one of the buttons is hovered over, all buttons on this style get the darker background** *(right portion of the image)*.

Has anyone come across similar issues? Any clues? :)
For reference I've posted my `MainWindow.xaml` and `AppUIResource.xaml` (the ResourceDictionary), which is when the issue appears to happen.

If you'd like to see when the style is working fine as expected (only triggers the instance that's being hovered over), simply cut and past the style from `AppUIResource.xaml` to `App.xaml`.

#### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="todelete_buttonTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:todelete_buttonTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="AppUIResource.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MainButton_1}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button Content="BUTTON 1"/>
            <Button Content="BUTTON 2"/>
            <Button Content="BUTTON 3"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### AppUIResource.xaml

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:todelete_buttonTest">
    
    <!--#region COLOR & BRUSH-->
    <Color x:Key="ThemeAccent1">#33cccc</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeAccent1Brush" Color="{StaticResource ThemeAccent1}"/>

    <Color x:Key="ThemeAccent2">#b7eded</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeAccent2Brush" Color="{StaticResource ThemeAccent2}"/>
    <!--#endregion Brushes-->

    <Style x:Key="MainButton_1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ThemeAccent1Brush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ThemeAccent1Brush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">

                    <Grid>
                        <Label x:Name="label"
                               Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                               Focusable="False"
                               FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="10,0,10,0"
                               Padding="0,0,0,0"
                               Panel.ZIndex="2"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        <Border x:Name="border_background"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Background="{StaticResource ThemeAccent2Brush}"
                                Opacity="0.3"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--Event triggers for styled animation-->
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="border_background" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="{StaticResource ThemeAccent1}"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0:0.3"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="border_background"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>

                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="{StaticResource ThemeAccent2}"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0:0.3"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="border_background"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>

                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="White"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0:0.1"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="label"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" 
                                                    AutoReverse="True"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got two kinds of solution.

#### 1. Merge `AppUIResource.xaml` into `App.xaml`.

- #### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="todelete_buttonTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:todelete_buttonTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MainButton_1}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button Content="BUTTON 1"/>
            <Button Content="BUTTON 2"/>
            <Button Content="BUTTON 3"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

- #### App.xaml

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="AppUIResource.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

#### 2. Set the **`Background`** of 'MainButton_1'

- #### AppUIResource.xaml

```xml
<Style x:Key="MainButton_1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <!--Set the Background-->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeAccent2Brush}"/>
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    ...
                    <!--TemplateBinding Background-->
                    <Border x:Name="border_background"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            .../>
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### And in addition,

you have defined `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave` EventTrigger, however, defining `IsMouseOver` Trigger has the same effect. Because when `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave` Event occurs, `IsMouseOver` property is changed internally. So you can try below code!

```xml
<!--Event triggers for styled animation-->
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="{StaticResource ThemeAccent1}"
                                    Duration="0:0:0:0.3"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="border_background"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="{StaticResource ThemeAccent2}"
                        Duration="0:0:0:0.3"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="border_background"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both of them work well. Still curious why there is this difference but thanks for quickly finding some workarounds for my issue. :)